# SQL code to project how many clients will reach age 55 each month for a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case, dateadd

I am trying to get the number of clients who are currently >= age 55, which I've managed, but next I want to find out how many people will be >= 55 in a month's time, then in 2 month's time etc up to 12 months.

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to go about the next bit. Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(year, -54, getdate()) AND [E].[MfChk4] = '0' 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END) AS [Age Eligible]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CR_Entity] [E]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CR_RefMaster] [RM] 
        ON  [RM].[EntCode] = [E].[EntClient] 
        AND [RM].[Status] = '0'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Compliance] [C] 
        ON  [C].[AddrCode] = [RM].[RefCode]
```

The result I want for the next bit will be something like...

[image: Example results]

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write multiple case statements like:

```
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+1, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = '0' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Month1,
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+2, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = '0' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Month2,
.
.
.
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+12, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = '0' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Month12
```

Comment: Yay that worked, thanks!  Probably a stupid question but is there any way to get the alias to show the actual month? Can you make the alias effectively (dateadd(month,1,getdate()) so the column names are Feb-20, Mar-20 etc?

Comment: Case _expressions_.

Answer (score 0):

To create the Naming convention you are looking, for you would have to use Dynamic SQL. You might have to change the query a bit, but the basics of it is:

```
--Declaring and calculating the Column Names

declare @test1 nvarchar(max),
        @test2 nvarchar(max),
        @test12 nvarchar(max)
set @test1='['+CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE()),'MMM-yy') as Varchar(20))+']'
set @test2='['+CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month,2,GETDATE()),'MMM-yy') as Varchar(20))+']'
.
.
.
set @test12='['+CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month,12,GETDATE()),'MMM-yy') as Varchar(20))+']'

--Writing the Dynamic Sql text

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(year, -54, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = ''0'' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [Age Eligible],
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+1, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = ''0''
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS' + @test1 + ',
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+2, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = ''0'' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS' + @test2 + ',
.
.
.
SUM
(CASE WHEN [C].[BirthDate] > dateadd(month,-54*12+12, getdate()) 
    AND [E].[MfChk4] = ''0'' 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS' + @test12 + '
FROM [dbo].[CR_Entity] [E]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CR_RefMaster] [RM] ON [RM].[EntCode] = [E].[EntClient] AND [RM].[Status] = ''0''
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Compliance] [C] ON [C].[AddrCode] = [RM].[RefCode]'

--Executing the Dynamic Sql query

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

You might want to start with one case statement to understand how it works and then implement it for the entire data.

Comment: Thanks so much, really helpful